# Make image move down on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently when I hover over an image it moves up, I would like it to move down when hovered instead, so the top of the image aligns with all of the other images.

CODE:

```js
$("ul.games li").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  }
);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #717e99;
}
section#banner .game-selector {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}
section#banner .game-selector ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -10px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0s ease;
}
section#banner .game-selector ul li.active {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 300px;
  height: 175px;
  background-position: center bottom;
}
section#banner .game-selector ul li.minecraft {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/UK5lBRh.png');
  background-position: center top;
}
section#banner .game-selector ul li.csgo {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/UK5lBRh.png');
  background-position: center top;
}
section#banner .game-selector ul li.gmod {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/UK5lBRh.png');
  background-position: center top;
}
section#banner .game-selector ul li.tf2 {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/UK5lBRh.png');
  background-position: center top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="game-selector">
        <ul class="games">
          <li class="csgo"></li>
          <li class="minecraft"></li>
          <li class="gmod"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4zh08gr5/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `top:5px` to the `.active`, change your `height:175px` in `.active` to `160px` which was the default you had.

Also I improved your jQuery code a bit.

```js
$("ul.games li").hover(function() {
  $('ul.games li').removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #717e99;
}
section#banner .game-selector {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}
section#banner .game-selector ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -10px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0s ease;
}
section#banner .game-selector ul li.active {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  background-position: center bottom;
  top: 5px
}
section#banner .game-selector ul li.minecraft {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/UK5lBRh.png');
  background-position: center top;
}
section#banner .game-selector ul li.csgo {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/UK5lBRh.png');
  background-position: center top;
}
section#banner .game-selector ul li.gmod {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/UK5lBRh.png');
  background-position: center top;
}
section#banner .game-selector ul li.tf2 {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/UK5lBRh.png');
  background-position: center top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="game-selector">
        <ul class="games">
          <li class="csgo"></li>
          <li class="minecraft"></li>
          <li class="gmod"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: In this example the physical image box still moves in an upward direction (when I run your snippet in full screen)

Comment: @user1910046 see updated answer, I changed your height in .active

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a CSS hover, instead of a jQuery hover. use `transform: translateY()` to easily move a div without disrupting other content around it.

```
section#banner .game-selector ul li:hover {
  transform: translateY(5px);
}
```

Here is an updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4zh08gr5/3/

Comment: The jQuery is used to append a class which then changes the image, notice the active class that changes the background position if you go to the image you'll see it's a sprite sheet